# When I Connect to mysql through c# it gives a fatal error

Tags: c#, mysql

When I execute this it gives a fatal error, nothing in my database. Someone please help. But, when I execute with 2 text boxes it worked fine. Column names are the same.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myConn = "server=localhost;database=check;uid=root;pwd=;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        String myInsertSQL ="INSERT INTO student VALUES(?Student_FName,?Student_LName,?Address_1,?Address_2,?DOB,?E-mail,?Batch_id,?Parent_FName,?Parent_LName)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myInsertSQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Student_FName",textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Student_LName",textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Address_1",textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Address_2",textBox4.Text); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?DOB",textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?E-mail",textBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Batch_id",textBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Parent_FName",textBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Parent_LName",textBox9.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//when executing it gives a fatal error
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error ? What is your question ?

Comment: Please be more exact! What is error that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You din't mention what is the exact error. But i think it is because you are using `?` instead of `@` in your parameter.

For example change `?Student_FName` To `@Student_FName`

And write the connection string as

```
string myConn = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=DBName;Uid=UserName;Pwd=Password;"
```

Also i see parameter as "E-mail", i guess its a typo. It should be "E_mail".

Comment: i tried that but didnt work

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: fatal error encountered  during command execution

Comment: Check your connection string, i have updated my answer.

Comment: The Problem is in email